# Q. How to select named element values from XSD string field

Tags: sql, xml, xsd, sql-server-2017

Within SQL Server I'm trying to select values from what I think is a XSD string.

e.g. Given the following SQL Server table

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.TextXML (
ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
Data NVARCHAR(max))

INSERT INTO dbo.TextXML ( ID, Data )
SELECT 1, 
       ('<element name="Rownum" value="Row23" />
          <element name="CONNECTIONTYPESECTION" value="True" />
          <element name="CustomFields" />
          <element name="EchoData">
            <element name="0000" value="8220000000000000" />
            <element name="0001" value="0400000100000000" />
            <element name="0007" value="0805193143" />
            <element name="MessageType" value="1234" />
          </element>
          <element name="ENABLESSL" value="false" />' )

INSERT INTO dbo.TextXML ( ID, Data )
SELECT 2, 
    ('<element name="Rownum" value="Row24" />
      <element name="CONNECTIONTYPESECTION" value="True" />
      <element name="CustomFields" />
      <element name="EchoData">
        <element name="0000" value="8220000000000000" />
        <element name="0001" value="0400000100000000" />
        <element name="0007" value="0805193143" />
        <element name="MessageType" value="5678" />
      </element>
      <element name="ENABLESSL" value="true" />' );
```

I want to be able to select the values for given element names. Something like ...

```
SELECT ID, Data.CONNECTIONTYPESECTION, Data.EchoData.0007, Data.EchoData.MessageType, Data.ENABLESSL
FROM TextXML
WHERE Data.Rownum = "Row23" AND Data.EchoData.MessageType = "1234".

ID  Data.CONNECTIONTYPESECTION Data.EchoData.0007 Data.EchoData.MessageType Data.ENABLESSL
1   True                       0805193143         1234                      true
```

I can use CHARINDEX and SUBSTRING but have to hardcode the length of the "**name**" value and this asumes the "**value**" is always the same length. I'm hoping there is a better and more efficient way do do this.

I have experimented with CROSS APPPLY and XML VALUE functions but this only returns the first element in the Data field. I also could not find out how to search for a particular element "**name**" to get its value

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following T-SQL.

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, Data NVARCHAR(max));
INSERT INTO @tbl (Data) VALUES
(N'<element name="Rownum" value="Row23"/>
    <element name="CONNECTIONTYPESECTION" value="True"/>
    <element name="CustomFields"/>
    <element name="EchoData">
        <element name="0000" value="8220000000000000"/>
        <element name="0001" value="0400000100000000"/>
        <element name="0007" value="0805193143"/>
        <element name="MessageType" value="1234"/>
    </element>
    <element name="ENABLESSL" value="false"/>'),
(N'<element name="Rownum" value="Row24"/>
    <element name="CONNECTIONTYPESECTION" value="True"/>
    <element name="CustomFields"/>
    <element name="EchoData">
        <element name="0000" value="8220000000000000"/>
        <element name="0001" value="0400000100000000"/>
        <element name="0007" value="0805193143"/>
        <element name="MessageType" value="5678"/>
    </element>
    <element name="ENABLESSL" value="true"/>');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

;WITH rs AS
(
    SELECT *
        , TRY_CAST(data AS XML) AS xmldata
    FROM @tbl
)
SELECT rs.ID
    , xmldata.value('(element[@name="CONNECTIONTYPESECTION"]/@value)[1]','VARCHAR(10)') AS CONNECTIONTYPESECTION
    , xmldata.value('(element[@name="EchoData"]/element[@name="0007"]/@value)[1]','VARCHAR(10)') AS [EchoData.0007]
    , xmldata.value('(element[@name="EchoData"]/element[@name="MessageType"]/@value)[1]','VARCHAR(10)') AS [EchoData.MessageType]
    , xmldata.value('(element[@name="ENABLESSL"]/@value)[1]','VARCHAR(10)') AS [Data.ENABLESSL]
FROM rs
WHERE xmldata.value('(element[@name="Rownum"]/@value)[1]','VARCHAR(30)') = 'Row23'
    AND xmldata.value('(element[@name="EchoData"]/element[@name="MessageType"]/@value)[1]','VARCHAR(10)') = '1234';
```

**Output**

```
+----+-----------------------+---------------+----------------------+----------------+
| ID | CONNECTIONTYPESECTION | EchoData.0007 | EchoData.MessageType | Data.ENABLESSL |
+----+-----------------------+---------------+----------------------+----------------+
|  1 | True                  |    0805193143 |                 1234 | false          |
+----+-----------------------+---------------+----------------------+----------------+
```

Comment: Awesome Yitzhak. That works lovely. Can you advise what flavour of xml/xsd this is so that I can find it easier in future searches?

Comment: @GregNelson, glad to hear that the proposed solution is working for you. Please don't forget to mark it as Answer. Your XML is not an XSD, it just visually resembles it.